# python global variable in fastApi not working as normal

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a simple fastApi demo app which achieve a function:
get different response json by calling a post api named changeResponse.
The changeResponse api just changed a global variable, another api return different response through the same global variable.On local env,it works correctly, but the response always changed after i just call changeResponse once when i build this on docker.The code is as follows:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from util import read_json
import enum

app = FastAPI()

type = "00"
    
@app.post("/changeResponse")
async def handle_change_download_response(param:Optional[str]):
        global type
        type = param
        print("type is "+type)
        return {"success":"true"}

@app.post("/download")
async def handle_download(param:Optional[str]):
    print("get download param: "+param)
    if legalDownload(param):
        print("type is "+type)
        return read_json.readDownloadSuccessRes(type)
    else:
        return read_json.readDownloadFailRes()

def legalDownload(data:str)->bool:
    return True
```

the dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

COPY ./app /app
```

what i except:
call changeResponse param is 7, get response for 7,
call changeResponse param is 8, get response for 8.
what i get:
call changeResponse param is 7,get reponse for 7,call changeReponse 8, sometime the response is 7, sometime is 8,impossible to predict

Comment: how did you send the data to the URL? I mean the parameter?

Comment: http://*.*.*.*/changeResponse?param=00  and use post method

Comment: i want to figure out how it happends ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi` is based on [uvicorn-gunicorn-docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-docker) image, which by defaults creates multiple workers. Excerpt from [gunicorn_conf.py](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-docker/blob/master/docker-images/gunicorn_conf.py):

`default_web_concurrency = workers_per_core * cores`

Thus, the described situation arises because the request is processed by **different workers** (processes). Each of which has its own copy of the global variable

Update: If you want to change the count of workers, use the following environment variables:

- **WORKERS_PER_CORE**: It will set the number of workers to the number of CPU cores multiplied by this value.
- **MAX_WORKERS**: You can use it to let the image compute the number of workers automatically but making sure it's limited to a maximum.
- **WEB_CONCURRENCY** Override the automatic definition of number of workers.

You can set it like:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -e WEB_CONCURRENCY="2" myimage
```

A more detailed description of these variables and examples [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-docker#workers_per_core)

---

If you want to share data between workers, pay attention to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65686318/13782669).

Comment: thanks,you are right, i solved this problem by set max_workers=1 when run docker image.

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue and got is fixed without changing the workers.

```
app = FastAPI()

app.type = "00"
```

Which I think is the best option.

Ref with many thanks : [fastapi/issues/592](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/592)

Answer (score 0):

I already known why:

> the fastapi use uvicorn run the app, and use gunicorn to manage these uvicorn
> the gunicorn in docker container default starts 2*num_of_core + 1 workers to run these uvicorn,so i assume there are three app in the server,and the request was sented to random worker to handle. that's why the response is random
> reference:https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html